# Prepared statement adding empty lines to mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am a bit lost with my prepared statement. My goal it to read a simple small csv file (100 lines and about 10 columns) into a mysql database. 
Since I couldn't get that to work I simplified the mysql table to one column for now (OrderUuid). The first part of the code I hardcoded a testvalue for my OrderUuid variable, which gets added to mysql fine. However, when I take the column value form the csv file (line[0]), nothing (an empty string I think) gets added to the db table.

Here is my code:

```
while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){

            //This works!
            $OrderUuid = "Test";
            $insertQry2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders_test (OrderUuid) VALUES (?)");
            $insertQry2->bind_param("s", $OrderUuid);
            if(!$insertQry2->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}

            //This doesn't
            $OrderUuid = $line[0];
            echo $OrderUuid."<br>"; //Returns something like: d17e91d5-63b9-4a56-a413-3274057073c7
            $insertQry3 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders_test (OrderUuid) VALUES (?)");
            $insertQry3->bind_param("s", $OrderUuid);
            if(!$insertQry3->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!
Norm

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks for all the tips guys! I rewrote the code, but unfortunately the script is still inserting empty strings into my table. There is no error messages whatsoever.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$flag = true;
$data = array();
while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){
    if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
    $data[] = $line;
}

if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders_test (OrderUuid) VALUES (?)"))) {
     echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $data[0][0])) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

foreach($data as $dat) {
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
}
```

Here is my super simple table:
    CREATE TABLE `orders_test` (
    `OrderUuid` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: How have you defined the connection with relation to error processing?

Comment: Is the `OrderUuid` column defined as big enough to hold `d17e91d5-63b9-4a56-a413-3274057073c7`

Comment: What is the value of `$conn->error`?

Comment: On the off chance that the warning gets suppressed, try replacing `trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING)` with `exit("there was an error....".$conn->error)` in the last line.

Comment: FYI, repeated statements are best prepared and bound outside any loops. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php#example-1831

Comment: You can also make MySQLi more *noisy* by placing this before creating your connection ~ `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! I edited my question. Unfortunately the script is still inserting empty strings into my table. See edit above please.

Comment: Any more suggestions from anyone ? Still stuck on this unfortunately..

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is interested, it was actually super simple in the end. The file contained some letters that the database interpreted as lots of line breaks I think. Therefore applying

```
strip_tags
```

did the trick.